# Can we resolve the centers of Milky way's satellite galaxies now?

Tags: black-hole, dwarf-galaxy

[Two dwarf satellite galaxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_galaxies_of_the_Milky_Way) of our galaxy have large $\frac{\text{diameter}}{\text{distance}}$ values. And one of them, Canis Major Dwarf, is 8kpc away which is 
the same with our distance to the galactic center.

Can we limit the masses(even they are not heavy) of their central black holes now? Like [Gillessen et al. 2009](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009ApJ...692.1075G), maybe we can find stars orbiting their central black holes.